# Why can't I use \ifstrequal to check the \jobname?

Tags: etoolbox, jobname

I want to use the same source file to compile various target files using the `-jobname` option. I want to ensure that the option is not forgotten, so my approach was to check whether the `\jobname` is equal to the source file name. The check does not work as expected:

```
% save as file mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
  \typeout{=== JOB: {\jobname} ===}
  \ifstrequal{\jobname}{mwe}{\errmessage{Please specify a different jobname.}}{}
  Job \jobname
\end{document}
```

If I compile this file with `pdflatex -jobname foo mwe.tex`, I get the following output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)) (./foo.aux)
=== JOB: {foo} ===
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./foo.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 10274 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

The problem is: If I compile it with `pdflatex mwe.tex`, it shows the job name `mwe`, but the expected error message does not appear:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)) (./mwe.aux)
=== JOB: {mwe} ===
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./mwe.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 11747 bytes).
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

I read about the catcode issue caused when using `\jobname` in combination with `\ifthen` -- however, according to the `etoolbox` documentation, `\ifstrequal` is catcode-agnostic. What else is going (wr)on(g) here?

Comment: Try `\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\jobname}{mwe}` or `\ifdefstring{\jobname}{mwe}`

Comment: You need to expand earlier `\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{`